# Adding installed widgets to Android activity

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget, buttonclick

I'm using Android Studio to create an Android Launcher app.

I'm trying to add a feature that allows the user to select an installed widget and place it on my launcher. Similar to what most launchers on the play store provide.

My code is currently is giving me `cannot resolve symbol` errors on `appWidgetHost` and `appWidgetManager`.

I've had a look on SO and Google on how to achieve this but I'm still confused on how to get this to work and how to correct my code.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.widgettest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button widgetButton;
    // APPWIDGET_HOST_ID is any number you like
    appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    appWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, 1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo newAppWidgetProviderInfo = new AppWidgetProviderInfo();

    // Get an id
    int appWidgetId = appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addwidgetButtonListener();

    }

   public void createwidget(){
       // Get the list of installed widgets
       List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> appWidgetInfos = new ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
       appWidgetInfos = appWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();



// Create Widget
       AppWidgetHostView hostView = appWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);
       hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);

// Add it to your layout
       RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
       rl.addView(hostView);
    }

    public void addwidgetButtonListener() {

        widgetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        widgetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
createwidget();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One cause of `Cannot resolve symbol` would be that you have not declared some variable. In this case, it looks like you forgot to declare appWidgetManager and appWidgetHost.

You can fix this error simply by prefixing the two lines with `AppWidgetManager` and `AppWidgetHost` respectively. Like so:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
AppWidgetHost appWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, 1);
```

On another note, I haven't done any work with the Widget Manager or Widget Host before, but in general anything that takes the Activity context as an argument should be initialized in the `onCreate` function. So, if you find that those variables are not being initialized properly while debugging your app, you would want to do something like this instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ...
   AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
   AppWidgetHost appWidgetHost;
   ...

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
       appWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, 1);
       ...
   }
```